# Json.NET: How to prevent a type from being serialized

Tags: json.net

When trying to serialize a list of objects of polymorphic types (say a `List<Shape>` with `Rectangle`, `Circle` and `Triangle` objects), I need to prevent objects of a certain type from being serialized (say `Circle`).
What's the best way to achieve this? The `JsonIgnore` attribute seems to apply to object-properties and not entire types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to ignore objects of a certain type, that are part of a list of objects of polymorphic types, from being serialized. What you can do is write a custom `JsonConverter` and decorate the `Circle` class with it. Example:

```
public class CircleJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and example of the `Circle` class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CircleJsonConverter))]
public class Circle : Shape
{
    public uint R { get; set; }
}
```

You can implement the `ReadJson` method to be able to deserialize json string into instances of `Circle` class. 
Drawback of this solution is that you won't be able to serialize into json string using JSON.NET any instance of the `Circle` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping there would be a more direct solution, maybe using some attribute, but this works. Fortunately, in my case `Circles` never need to be serialized.